# Create CSS arrow with unknown height

Tags: html, css

I used http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/ to create arrows with css.

```
ul li div.arrow{
 position: absolute;
 width: 0;
 height: 0;
 top: 0;
 right: -30px;
 border-left: 15px solid red;
 border-top: 30px solid transparent;
 border-right: 15px solid transparent;
 border-bottom: 30px solid transparent;
```

It works when i know the height of the arrow. But now i want to create an arrow with an unknown height. I created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/69vVj/1/) to show you what i want to do.

As you can see the last item is higher and the arrow is not filling the complete height of the li

Is there a way to make these arrows fill the complete height of the li without using Javascript?

Comment: What you will need is [this](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=css+responsive+triangle&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&gws_rd=cr&ei=6E_rUqe4H4uMrgfUl4DIDA)

Answer (score 3):

Following on from Vals' CSS-only example, this example uses the same basic CSS code, but it is applied to pseudo elements of the `li`, meaning the extra divs are not needed.

CodePen: http://cdpn.io/wlKHj

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

ul{
    list-style-type: none;
    width: 200px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
ul li{
    background-color: red;
    padding: 20px 30px 20px 10px;
    color: #000000;
    position: relative;
    border-top: 1px solid #000000;
}

li:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10;
    width: 30px;
    bottom: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    right: -30px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to top right, red 50%, transparent 51%), linear-gradient(to bottom right, red 50%, transparent 51%);
    background-size: 100% 50% ;
    background-position: top left, bottom left;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<ul>
    <li>
        test 1
    </li>
    <li>
        test 1
    </li>
    <li>
        test 2
    </li>
    <li>
        test 3
    </li>
    <li>
        test 4 test 4 test 4 test 4 test 4 test 4
    </li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

For a CSS solution:

```
ul li div.arrow{
    position: absolute;
    width: 30px;
    bottom: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    right: -30px;
     background-image: linear-gradient(to top right, red 50%, transparent 51%), linear-gradient(to bottom right, red 50%, transparent 51%);
    background-size: 100% 50% ;
    background-position: top left, bottom left;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/69vVj/18/)

Comment: Nice work! I messed around with that for quite a while but gave up. Forgot about background gradients. I also wanted to use `:after` instead of a div. Might try that now. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Use following code

```
$(function(){
 $("ul li").each(function(){
   var height = $(this).innerHeight()/2;                
   $(this).find(".arrow").css({'border-top':height + 'px solid transparent','border-bottom':height + 'px solid transparent',})
   });
});
```

Comment: a little note that this involves the use of an external library would be useful

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to load jQuery but would like a JS solution, this also seems to work:

```
(function() {
    var listitems = document.querySelectorAll('ul li');
    for (var i=0; i<listitems.length; i++) {
        var height = listitems[i].offsetHeight/2;
        var arrow = listitems[i].querySelector('.arrow');
        arrow.style.borderTop = height + 'px solid transparent';
        arrow.style.borderBottom = height + 'px solid transparent';
    }
}());
```